# Is there a shorthand for addition assignment operator for nullables that sets the value if null?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am using nullable doubles to store the sum of some values pulled from various sources. The sum could be any real value or null if no elements are present.

Currently, I use a null check and either assign or increment:

```
double? sum = null;
...    
if(sum == null)
    sum = someTempValue;
else
    sum += someTempValue;
```

I know c# has several shorthand null checks for method calls and the such. My question is if there is a shorthand notation to the addition assignment operator `+=` when using nullables that assigns the value if `null` or performs the operation if `not null`?

Comment: sum = sum == null ? someTempValue : sum + someTempValue

Comment: What about sum = (sum ?? 0) + someTempValue ?

Comment: What is wrong with your if statement?

Comment: More info on the '?' operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Nothing is wrong with the if statement. I was just wondering if there was a shorthand for this. I find c# has a ton of short-handedness for nulls and was wondering if one existed for this. Plus this is for a data skimmer and even a few of these gets a little messy.

Comment: Put it in a separate method?

Comment: If you're sticking in loads of `if statements` everywhere then it sounds like you need to rethink you're design rather than worrying about shorthand null checks.

Comment: @sr28 By few I mean three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put ternary operator:

```
double? sum = null;
sum = sum == null ? someTempValue : sum + someTempValue;
```

Or

```
sum = someTempValue + (sum == null ? 0 : sum);
```

Or

```
sum = someTempValue + (sum ?? 0);
```

Credit to: [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) for the last option

Comment: That is not a shorthand for the addition assignment operator as OP asked, but I guess that is the shortest code possible.

Comment: Ah yes, it is fitter to say that this is shortest code possible rather than shorthand for the addition assignment

Comment: `sum = someTempValue + (sum ?? 0);`

Comment: @Ian: a typical use of *ternary operator* (when `if else` brings only *complexity*, but not *readability*). +1

Comment: ah yes, it is exactly as you said. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a *real* shortcut, but quite *compact*:

```
sum = sum ?? 0 + someTempValue;
```

treat `sum` as `0` when `sum == null`. But, please, notice that `??` operator can be *dangerous*:

```
// parenthesis () are mandatory, otherwise you'll have a wrong formula
// (someTempValue + sum) ?? 0;
sum = someTempValue + (sum ?? 0);
```

Comment: upvoted, as the last option of my answer is from your comment

Comment: @Ian: I've answered just to show up that `??` solution being a *compact* has a *flaw*: it's easy to get a wrong formula.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from the post, but looks like the `someTempValue` is **non nullable**, otherwise the `if` logic will not work because `+` operator will destroy the previous sum if the `someTempValue` is `null`.

If that's true, then you can utilize the null-coalescing operator and the fact that `null + value == null`:

```
sum = (sum + someTempValue) ?? someTempValue;
```

If `someTempValue` is also nullable, then the correct logic would be:

```
sum = (sum + someTempValue) ?? someTempValue ?? sum;
```

IMO, with shorthand or not, it's better to put that logic in a method

```
public static class MathUtils
{
    public static double? Add(double? left, double? right)
    {
        // The avove shorthand
        return (left + right) ?? right ?? left;
        // or another one
        //return left == null ? right : right == null ? left : left + right;
    }
}
```

and use simple

```
sum = MathUtils.Add(sum, someTempValue);
```

or with C#6 `using static` feature, the even shorter

```
sum = Add(sum, someTempValue);
```