# Subscribe to events of a nullable class

Tags: c#, events, nullable

I'm subscribing to an event generated by a class that might be null as follows:

```
if (eventGeneratingClass != null)
  eventGeneratingClass.myEvent += myHandler;
```

In the event generating class a construct like

```
myEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

can be used. I was wondering if a similar construct could be used when (de)subscribing to an event, e.g.:

```
eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent += myHandler;
eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent -= myHandler;
```

I've found both
[Is there a shorthand for addition assignment operator for nullables that sets the value if null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295114/is-there-a-shorthand-for-addition-assignment-operator-for-nullables-that-sets-th) and 
[How to call custom operator with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113259/how-to-call-custom-operator-with-reflection)

which lead me to: [Operator Overloading Usage Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7(v=vs.71).aspx)

Which lead me to trying

```
eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent.op_AdditionAssignment(myHandler);
eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent.op_SubtractionAssignment(myHandler);
```

but it doesn't seem that an event has an `op_AdditionAssignment` memberfunction or at least provides me with the error

> the event 'EventGeneratingClass.myEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=...

Which is where I got stuck...

Comment: You're probably looking for add/remove https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add .. *but* I don't think that'll work if your object itself is null, because there won't be anything to call the add/remove of, haven't tried though

Comment: You were looking for `eventGeneratingClass?.add_myEvent(myHandler)` but this won't work anyway, compiler will say "cannot explicitly call operator or accessor". So you have to just live with the fact you have to use `if` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The null conditional operation `?.` returns null when the left side expression is null.

So in

> ```
> eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent += myHandler
> ```

if `eventGeneratingClass` is null then `eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent` is null. And trying to attach an event listener to null will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

While the `?.` operator does make handling nulls easier, it doesn't eliminate handling them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution using null-conditional operators than it seems you are out of luck. From the [C# draft specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#null-conditional-expressions-as-statement-expressions):

> **Null-conditional expressions as statement expressions**
>
> A null-conditional expression is only allowed as a statement_expression (Expression statements) if it ends with an invocation. Grammatically, this requirement can be expressed as:
>
> ```
> null_conditional_invocation_expression
>     : primary_expression null_conditional_operations '(' argument_list? ')'
>     ;
> ```
>
> This is a special case of the grammar for null_conditional_expression above. The production for statement_expression in Expression statements then includes only null_conditional_invocation_expression.

So you would need to call `+=` as `+=(myHandler)` (i.e. `eventGeneratingClass?.myEvent?.+=(myHandler)`), which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void IfNotNull<T>(this T instance, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            action(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call

```
someInstance.IfNotNull(_ => _.SomethingHappened += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    // code
});
```

But then again you could even use the `if` clause, since the extension method does not make the code less verbose.